# Listing Files in Bash using Regex

Tags: regex, bash

I have a case where I need to find/list files in certain directory in Bash using Regex.

```
  myRegex="MYFILE[0-9]{15}"
  if [[ `ls` =~ "$myRegex" ]]
  then
      echo "Matching File found"
  else
      echo "No Matching File found"
  fi
```

eventhough I have files matching this regex in the directory, it still gives "No matching file found" error.

Thanks for answer in advance

Comment: I think you need to remove the `"` from around `"$myRegex"`

Comment: Oh yes....this works. Thats crazy...I've been trying around multiple things...but sometimes the answers are way too straightforward. Thanks Wiktor!

Comment: Well, Will has posted the same answer, no need to double up. BTW, why is there a Java tag? The regex is not Java specific. I removed the Java tag, it is redundant.

Comment: If one of the answers below solved your problem, please accept the answer to mark this question as resolved. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually the quotations. This should fix it:

```
MY_REGEX="MYFILE[0-9]{15}"
if [[ "$(ls)" =~ $MY_REGEX ]]; then
    echo "Matching File found"
else
    echo "No Matching File found"
fi
```

Bash expects regex literals, not a string.